# Prove that $ \lim_\limits{x \to \infty} x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x) $ = $ \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

How can you prove that $$ \lim_\limits{x \to \infty}  x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x) =  \frac{1}{2} \text{ ?}$$

I can not find a way to *calculate* this.

This is one *idea*:
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}  x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x) \approx \lim_\limits{x \to \infty}  x(\sqrt{x^2}-x) = 0 $$ but that is wrong.

Comment: Multiply by conjugate quantity.

Comment: Hint: use the formula $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ on the expression in brackets.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{x^2+1}+x$

Comment: See also: [Why is $x(\sqrt{x^2+1} - x )$ approaching $1/2$ when $x$ becomes infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1080637)
and [Why is $\lim_{x\to \infty} x(\sqrt{x^2+1} - x) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831340)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Here is another idea $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x (x^2  +1 - x^2)}{\sqrt{x^2  +1} + x} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2  +1} + x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1  +\frac{1}{x^2}} + 1} = \ldots$$

Comment: If it's not clear what was done here, see Claude Leibovici's comment under the question. ${}\qquad{}$